Rails 5.2 routes with nested dynamic segment not working
I've upgrade rails from 5.1.6 to 5.2.8 and it have a problem with Routing using nested Dynamic Segments.
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|de/ do
    scope "(:country_prefix)", country_prefix: /jp|vn/ do
      root to: "partner/top_pages#show", as: :partner_prefix_root
      resources :users
    end
  end
end

When I access page: "localhost:3000/en/vn"
On 5.1.6 it ok
On 5.2.8 it return an error like ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/en/vn")
Is there any change for 5.2.8 version?
